# Count DB Table Rows / Products QTY

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an little Laravel 5 Store with Product Autofill / Autoship option.

I can Upload many Products and after an buyer purchase it he get the Item instantly from DB .

No i want count the Quantity how much Products are available for Autoshipping.

With this, i get all Products where saved in DB for one Product:

```
{{$product->autofill}}
```

But i want only the Counts from Quantity theres available.

I have Try this an many other:

```
<?php $count = DB::table('products')->where(['autofill' => $product->autofill])->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

and

```
<?php $count = DB::table('products')->whereIn('autofilled', [1])->where(['autofill' => $product->autofill])->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

But dont work for me. Because its then for all items not for just one that i visit.
It must visible for every Product separate.

```
Example:

Sugar: 12 Products Available for Autoshipping
Milk:  35 Products Available for Autoshipping
```

But i cant just count the table because all Autofill items are in one row.

Someone can help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What information `$product->autofill` has in it? Is it a boolean?

Comment: Yes has in it  Url Links

Comment: So, if `autofill` field will be the same for several products and you want to know how many? Is that correct?